# Is "OpenCV dnn readnet forward" compatible among different versions of OpenCV?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, onnx

I can successfully run the following code and get the desired results with OpenCV 4.5.5. However, the same code generates wrong and strange output if I upgrade OpenCV to version 4.6.0 and above. What is the reason and how to solve it?

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNet(onnxmodel)
# Runs the forward pass to get output of the output layers
outs = net.forward(net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames())
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you upgraded it to 4.6.0 or let pip install the latest one? Because when you don't let it upgrade automatically, 4.6.0 module is going to be installed in a different package. The latest version is the 4.7.0, actually. Remove that specific one and just use the latest one from opencv-python which will overwrite the previous and then you can use the latest one.

```
pip install --upgrade opencv-python
```

Comment: The question is not about how to use the latest version of OpenCV, I can use any version of Opencv successfully. The question is why don't I get the same output with different versions of OpenCV?